# How to hide some fields for response in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Another DRF newbie here.

I want to hide some fields in response of my REST API.

Let's say I have, some basic **Exchange Service**:

**serializers.py**

```
class ConversionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = serializers.FloatField()
    from_ = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
    to_ = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
    converted_value = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    ....
```

**views.py**

```
class ConversionAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ConversionSerializer
    permission_classes = []

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
        ....
```

For my **POST** request I pass 3 values: value, from, to. And in response I get 4 values: value, from, to, converted_value.

```
{
    "value": 100,
    "from_": "foo",
    "to_": "bar",
    "converted_value": 200
}
```

Now, I want to get only **converted_value** in response instead of all fields. How to implement it? Thanks

Comment: you can use extra_kwargs = {'value': {'write_only': True}} in Serializer class

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the [write_only](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only) argument for that:

```
class ConversionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = serializers.FloatField(write_only=True)
    from_ = serializers.ChoiceField(write_only=True, choices=SOME_CHOICES)
    to_ = serializers.ChoiceField(write_only=True, choices=SOME_CHOICES)
    converted_value = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    ....
```

Comment: if you want to have a more complex control, you'll have to play with to_representation and decide when you discard it or not.